# What's a good source for SharePoint 2013 Workflow instructional info?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

A library and Amazon search only provided 1 book that isn't being published until September. I checked out the author's website and there wasn't anything specific to the question there. Lynda.com doesn't have anything technical in that aspect.

I'm basically a power user looking to take advantage of Designer. I'm not a developer, so trying to stay away from the Visual Studio route.

Right now I'm trying to build a workflow in SharePoint Online Plan 1 that:

1. initiates from a new list item,
2. creates a subsite and associated groups (http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2012/06/released-sandboxed-sharepoint-workflow.html)
3. alerts external users there's a new item to review
4. Get those users to accept or reject a task of leaving feedback
5. Get the accepted users' feedback to 3-4 questions
6. Send that info to the item creator
7. then item creator selects users (that accepted in step 4) to be added to that SharePoint group.

I haven't played with Designer since the 2007 version so a basic introduction to the menus and options would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 SharePoint 2013 Workflow courses on Pluralsight:

http://beta.pluralsight.com/search/?searchTerm=sharepoint%20workflow

> SharePoint 2013 Workflow Fundamentals
>
> SharePoint 2013 Workflow Advanced Topics
>
> SharePoint 2013 Workflow - Web Services

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Just signed up and getting to work.